# How do I make a random reply for my discord bot (in python)

Tags: python, discord

I am new to making discord bots, and currently have some basic code that allows a user to write a command and then my bot would reply to the command provided. I just want to know how I can make a random reply appear out of a list of options.
Once again, I am new to making bots, and don't know that much about them. Some help would be greatly appreciated. (also im sorry if i missed anything, I am new to this platform)

```
import discord
import os
import random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Current user logged {0.user}'.format(client))
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith(']hi'):
    await message.channel.send('hello')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create list of "answer choices".

A list always looks like this: `["Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3"]`

Here you can enter your desired answers.
When executing a command/event an entry should be selected from this list. You do this as follows:

```py
random = ["entry1", "entry2", "entry3"]
await message.channel.send(f"{random.choice(random)}") # Choose one random output
```

I would put the whole thing in one command, so make the following out of it:

```py
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
async def random(ctx):
random = ["entry1", "entry2", "entry3"]
await ctx.send(f"{random.choice(random)}")
```

***For more examples have a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).***

Comment: I made a new file to test the code you provided and it gave me an error saying "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    @client.command()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command' "

Comment: Have you imported `from discord.ext import commands`?

Comment: Try `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YourPrefix")`

Comment: it gives me 12 different errors when I try to put this in to my main code, even though it worked perfectly fine on it's own.

Comment: I think it is because of how you define `client`. With the current code you are not able to use `client.command` for the time being, if I am right.

Comment: yes, I think that is the problem. I define "client" as `discord.Client`. I will try to fix it and tell you the outcome